# Merb having issues requiring gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, merb, rmagick

I have merb setup but when I try to run it I get issue with any gems I try to include, e.g. I have the following:

```
require 'RMagick'
```

The rmagick gem is installed, and doing the above in irb (after requiring `rubygems` works as expected) even putting `require 'rubygems'` before I require RMagick doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah-ha seems that it was getting confused with the frozen(?) gems in the gems/ directory under my app, removing that completely fixed the issue. Will look into that further.